# What causes the stuttering framerate in this simple SDL rendering loop?

Tags: c++, windows-7, sdl

I wrote a very basic test to see if SDL would work properly on my system. I assumed it would run perfectly smoothly because the drawing code is very simple, but it is not smooth at all, and looks bad in different ways depending on the frame rate that I specify.

My hope is that I have done something silly. My worry is that the code is fine, but my Windows 7 machine won't play nicely with SDL. I've tinkered and googled excessively, but I can't figure out what's going on. Can someone more knowledgeable see a problem? The code is below:

```
#include "SDL.h"

static int g_width = 1024;
static int g_height = 768;

static int g_frameWaitInterval = 20;   // 50fps
static int g_lastFrameTime = 0;

static int g_ballx = 200;
static int g_bally = 200;
static int g_ballSize = 20;
static int g_ballxVelocity = 5;

void Step();
void Draw();

// Main application loop
void Run(){        
    while(true){
        if(SDL_GetTicks() - g_lastFrameTime >= g_frameWaitInterval){
            g_lastFrameTime = SDL_GetTicks();
            Step();
            Draw();
        }
    }
}

// Bounces the ball back and forth across the screen
void Step(){
    g_ballx += g_ballxVelocity;
    if(g_ballx+g_ballSize>=g_width){
        g_ballx = g_width - (g_ballSize+1);
        g_ballxVelocity = -g_ballxVelocity;
    }
    if(g_ballx<0){
        g_ballx = 0;
        g_ballxVelocity = -g_ballxVelocity;
    }
}

// Draws the ball as a square
void Draw(){
    SDL_Surface* p_screen = SDL_GetVideoSurface();
    SDL_FillRect(p_screen, NULL, 0xff000000);

    SDL_Rect rect;
    rect.x = g_ballx; rect.y = g_bally;
    rect.w = rect.h = g_ballSize;
    SDL_FillRect(SDL_GetVideoSurface(), &rect, 0xffff00ff);

    SDL_UpdateRect(p_screen,0,0,0,0);
}

// Initialises SDL, etc (checking removed for brevity)
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    SDL_SetVideoMode(g_width, g_height, 0, SDL_SWSURFACE);
    Run();
    return 0;
}
```

**Edit:** I ran a framerate test over the course of 10 seconds and got 49.76, which is very close to the 50fps I was expecting. I also printed out a huge number of individual frame timings and found that every frame took 20ms, as expected. This suggests to me that the problem is with some aspect of the configuration, rather than my rendering loop.

Answer (score 2):

You may just need to set up double buffering.  Without it you can get a little bit of flickering, even on simple programs.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it made no difference :/ (See my response to cgurleyuk)

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem is that you are using a busy loop, and Windows probably throttles your process, or something like that.

Also, if you want the animation to run smoothly you should add `g_frameWaitInterval` to g_lastFrameTime, instead of updating it to the return of SDL_GetTicks(). Otherwise you may accumulate differences and make the animation uneven.

Try the following:

```
void Run(){        
    while(true){
        Uint32 now = SDL_GetTicks();
        Uint32 dif = now - g_lastFrameTime;

        if (now  >= g_lastFrameTime + g_frameWaitInterval){
            g_lastFrameTime += g_frameWaitInterval;
            Step();
            Draw();
            if (now  >= g_lastFrameTime + g_frameWaitInterval){
                //You are losing time! Correct it!
                g_lastFrameTime = now;
            }
        }
        else {
            //Play nice with CPU time
            SDL_Delay(g_frameWaitInterval - dif);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks different with your loop, but still not smooth. I actually avoided using SDL_Delay because I've seen a lot of people advise against it, as it (apparently) doesn't provide the granularity that you would expect. Apparently it typically works in blocks of 10ms, at the minimum, so if you ask it to delay for x milliseconds it might actually delay for as long as x+10 milliseconds.

I also tried it without SDL_Delay, but keeping your astute observation about the accumulated error. Still jerky :/

Comment: @Nem You are right about the granularity, but note that this also affects `SDL_GetTicks()`. Have you checked if you have any other process consuming a lot of CPU? And raising the priority of your process from the task manager?

Comment: I tried the priority and that made no difference, but that isn't surprising since I'm working on a computer with an intel i7 that presumably has plenty of idle hardware threads lying around. Are you sure that SDL_GetTicks() can be that inaccurate? The documentation doesn't mention anything (it does for SDL_Delay). I will look into it anyway. Thanks!

Comment: @Nem Just try calling SDL_GetTicks() in a tight loop and print all the results. It's been a time since I last tried it in Windows, maybe it changed...

Comment: Ah, very clever. I just tried that and I can confirm that it transitioned smoothly between each millisecond. I obviously can't confirm that it was transitioning *accurately* between each one, but it seems unlikely to be the source of the problem in my case. It's also worth noting that it is used to regulate framerate in every SDL tutorial that I've seen.

Comment: If you're interested, I edited some extra information into the bottom of my original question. I ran a few tests to get a better idea of where the problem is.

Comment: -1 SDL_Delay is not guaranteed to sleep for the time provided. This is entirely up to the scheduler and it may sleep for longer than you specify.

Answer (score 0):

To get perfectly smooth sequences of images, you need to both set up double buffering (where you draw into one image, while another is shown on the screen, and swap them after your drawing procedure is done), and vsync, where you cap your frame rate to the refresh rate of your monitor, thus avoiding tearing effects. On modern systems, these two effects are the only probable factors I can think of that could result in choppy, flickery animation.

Comment: I tried enabling double buffering, but saw no improvement. I also tried setting the full screen flag, and then the hardware surface flag, just in case these were prerequisites to vsync actually kicking in, but none of that had any impact at all. When you think about it, this should be drawing the square near-instantaneously at exactly the right time anyway, so stuff like double buffering and vsync shouldn't make much of a difference.

Comment: @Nem Even though you set the hardware surface flag you may still actually be getting a software surface. If you uncap the frame rate and use double buffering does it reduce tearing?

Comment: Double buffering and vsync _always_ matters, even when drawing a single polygon in hardware. The monitor outputs images at a fixed refresh rate; and you fps constitutes another frequency. If these are not in sync, you're going to see the beat frequencies on the screen; which will result in flickery, tearing images.

Comment: Have you tried relaxing the FPS cap you're setting on the render loop? I am positive 50 fps and a 60Hz refresh rate would result in tearing, even if double buffered. And vsync wouldn't kick in no matter what, since your frame rate is capped at 50fps.

Comment: @ZackTheHuman I can't really remove the cap because the loop would run too fast, but I increased it to 250fps and it does appear to be quite smooth now. I wouldn't say that the problem was tearing in the first place. It looked more like skipped frames, or delayed frames, which does fit quite well with the description of vsync problems given here: http://hardforum.com/showthread.php?t=928593

Comment: I don't really feel like I have gotten to the bottom of what is going on, as it does seem like I should be able to get a smooth 60Hz animation by actually drawing 60 frames per second. Very similar code is used in other tutorials without any mention of these problems, so I am quite puzzled. Maybe I am just mistaken in thinking this...